# Trying to replace all instances of a character in an object properties values

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to replace all instances of a character in an object properties values

I'm stuck here. I can't figure out how to modify the value.

```
for(let [key, val] in obj){
     if(typeof val === "string"){ 
     ???? = val.replace(/,/g, '')
     }
}
```

Comment: `obj[key] = val.replace`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use destructuring to iterate over an object's properties and values with `for-in`.

And in order to replace the value, you have to use an object accessor, you can't replace with destructuring.

```
for (let key in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[key] == "string") {
        obj[key] = obj[key].replace(/,/g, '');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
const obj = { a1: "aaaa,11,aa",  b2: "bbbb,22,bb"};

Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, val]) => obj[key] = val.replace(/,/g, ""));

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => (obj[key] = obj[key].replace("A", "n")));
```

Comment: You have `Object.entries()` for that purpose.

Comment: If I can access `value` with `key` why do I access `value` by itself using `entries`?